# How to return back to the application after webview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, stripe-connect

The flow of application requires user to go to a  webpage and update few details after which the user need to come back with id that website has provided.

**Working senario:**

```
User logs in application 
  clicks button goes to the website update few details 
  stays in the Webview for the website
```

**Required Senario:**

```
Should come back to the app with the id that website provided
```

The flow of the app is something similar to google Oauth where the user clicks the google button to authenticate google to use the google account.

Comment: You've tagged this with `UIWebView` but you also say "come back to the app".  If you're using a `UIWebView` you haven't *left* the app.  Can you clarify the actual structure?

Comment: apologize for the confusion, i meant to come back to return back to previous UIController as the webview fills up the screen there's no what the user can go back to the previous view

Answer (score 0):

You can show the web page in a WKWebView. Assuming you also are coding the web page you can also use [evaluateJavaScript(*:completionHandler:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) to figure out when the website is done, grab the result, and dimiss the WKWebView.  Alternatively you can intercept the success navigation with the WKNAvigationDelegate method [webView(:didStartProvisionalNavigation:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455621-webview) and then grab whatever info you need from the server.

Comment: The webpage is a third party application, so wont be able to perform the above said action

Comment: then intercept the navigation.